# What is this item and what is it for?

Tags: brutal-doom

I've seen this item a number of times now, but I can't seem to pick it up.

[image: Circular saw thing]

Is this an actual weapon or item? It looks like a circular saw of some sort.  I can't seem to pick it up at all, but since I've seen it multiple times (often placed like it is in this picture), I'm thinking it's some sort of weapon.  What is this thing and does it have any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually just the chainsaw despite it not looking anything like one.  I looked through the controls and found that there was a "drop weapon" key. I thought maybe if I dropped my chainsaw, it would let me pick this item up next time I came across it.  After dropping the chainsaw I already had, I was surprised to see it *was* this item.

[image: Chainsaw gif]

Given how fast pace this game can be at times, I probably picked up my chainsaw rapidly (and many levels ago), which is why I had no idea what this item was.